# Wicked pdf rendering the last row across two pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf, wicked-pdf

I am using [wicked_pdf](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf) to generate pdfs. The problem i am facing is that, sometimes it displays the last row in the page across two pages. Is there a way to tell wicked_pdf to render the row in next page if it can't fit the entire row in that page or set a limit on the number of rows in a page?

Below image is an example of my problem.

[image: Below image is an example of my problem]

My options are

```
render :pdf => file_name,
       :layout => "pdf.html",
       :disposition => "attachment"
```

Answer (score 3):

Since WickedPDF isn't actually creating a table (just rendering one from the html/css) there aren't many options available - you can try using `page-break-inside: avoid;` in your css, you may also need to manually break down the sizes of the tables so that the effect of avoiding page breaks isn't too severe.

css:

```
table, tr, td, th, tbody, thead, tfoot {
    page-break-inside: avoid;
}
```

That should get you started, at least.

Edit: Here is another question on this subject with some further info: [How to avoid page break inside table row for wkhtmltopdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13516534/how-to-avoid-page-break-inside-table-row-for-wkhtmltopdf)

Comment: I added page-break-inside. But it is still happening.

Comment: It still happening for me too. :(

Comment: Try updating tyour wkhtml version to at least `0.12.1`.

Comment: Did anyone found solution to this problem?

Comment: I just added 
`.avoidPageBreaks { page-break-inside: avoid !important; }` to the element I don't want to be broken. In my case was just on `table` elements.
The additional question suggested by Matt provides solution.

Comment: If you want the table to still appear in more than 1 page (so it doesn't leave "empty spaces", just remove from the selector `table`

Answer (score 0):

I have had this same problem. There is no easy answer. You have to close the entire table and issue the `.page-break` (I define `.page-break {page-break-before:always}` in my css) outside the table.  Then, start a new table and continue to render from where you were at. It's not easy!  I ended up counting rows, and even checking for size of cell content to get to cell rows, and just closing the table and restarting as needed.

Definitely a limitation of the HTML to PDF process.