# yii php wkhtmltopdf data gets cut off at bottom

Tags: php, yii, centos, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf

Any plugin i use in PHP produces the same results. I have read [Wkhtmltopdf Characters in single line partially cut between pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8786755/wkhtmltopdf-characters-in-single-line-partially-cut-between-pages) and followed through with some instruction in the bug reports. I am using Yii framework and on the view using `CGridView`. I have placed the following on the style sheets.

```
.nobreak,  table tr, table tr td {
    page-break-inside: avoid;
}
```

This fix does not work and text still gets cut off. If i open the page in html and use the pdf printer from adobe it works fine. but i need the pdf to be auto generated.

```
 wkhtmltopdf --version
Name:
  wkhtmltopdf 0.11.0 rc1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

latest releases fixes this issue http://wkhtmltopdf.org/ v0.12.1 as of writing

Comment: I'm using 0.12.1 and I'm still getting lines splitting at the bottom of each PDF using Ubuntu 12.04.5