# Rotativa.AspNetCore page break half of line goes next page

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, rotativa

I have a very big view which needs to be converted to PDF. I have used Rotativa but it is not properly page breaking, half of the line goes to next page and I don't know where needs to use page break because my view model generate dynamically.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried these?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8786755/wkhtmltopdf-characters-in-single-line-partially-cut-between-pages

Comment: Thank your very much @TamásHuj. It's solved my problem by using 'page-break-inside: avoid' for my every div.

Comment: Ok, in this case I add this as answer.

Answer (score 1):

Rotativa is built on top of wkhtmltopdf library, so this means that the same solutions from this post should also be a good for you: [Wkhtmltopdf Characters in single line partially cut between pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8786755/wkhtmltopdf-characters-in-single-line-partially-cut-between-pages)